# Doesn't update days in database (Python and sqlite)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have two columns in my database: Expired dates and days left. I already had registered a couple of data in my tables. Every day, the days left should keep update so I did this code.

```
def update_days():
current_date = datetime.now().date()

conn = sqlite3.connect("student.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT expired FROM inventory")
fetch = cursor.fetchall()
for row in fetch:
    string1 = convertTuple(row)
    date_object = datetime.strptime(string1, '%B-%d-%Y').date()
    delta = date_object - current_date
    days_left =(delta.days)
    print(days_left)
    cursor.execute("UPDATE inventory SET description = ? WHERE expired = ?", (days_left, string1))    

def convertTuple(tup): 
str =  ''.join(tup) 
return str
```

First, I fetch all the expired dates from the database. Then, I've converted the tuples into a string so that I can get the dates again and subtract them to the current date. The problem is the values of days_left doesn't update to database. Can you guys help me ?

Comment: Your UPDATE statement has no WHERE clause which makes it updating whole table on every run of a loop

Comment: Oh, its incompleted. Idk if its right but can you check it again ?

Comment: Now it's okay but I still have no idea why it shouldn't work. Everything seems to be fine from the SQL perspective

Comment: `cursor.execute("UPDATE inventory SET description = ? WHERE expired = ?", (days_left, string1))`  I don't know if the value of expired = ? should be the converted tuple. I tried to place this code outside of the for loop but still doesn't work.

Comment: Run the following against a TEST database. change the UPDATE statement to "UPDATE inventory SET description = 9" and check whether your loop is being executed at all. If so, all the tuples in the table should have description = 9. Optionaly you might append a "break" or whatever is needed to abort the execution after the first run of the loop

Comment: Oh I tested it and found out that I forgot the commit() method. Btw, thank you for helping me, really appreciated man.

Comment: No problems, this is a type of errors everyone does. Good luck